# Is a broken staff a death sentence?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am a Sorcerer in Dark Souls 2. I broke my staff while working my way through the Forest of the Fallen Giants. It seems I don't have much power, and can't effectively use a sword. Is there hope for me, or should I just restart?

I have around 700 souls saved up at the moment. I can kill an occasional guy or two, but it isn't easy, as if it ever is in Dark Souls...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can repair broken equipment at the blacksmith, who you can unlock very early in the Forest of Fallen Giants, so you won't need to restart.

You didn't specify how far into the area you got, but you only need to get to the Cardinal Tower bonfire, which is the second one in the area. Next to the bonfire is an old woman who sells the Lenigrast Key for 1000 souls. Buy it and return to Majula to repair your staff.

Comment: There was a tunnel next to a white guy who was sleeping. Didn't find the second bonfire yet.

Comment: What's sad is now that I look at it, where I broke my staff I was almost at the bonfire, and probably could have trudged my way to it. But I chickened out with a broken staff, and now will have to figure out a way to make it with the broken staff...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto The way from the first to the second bonfire is really short. You could try running past the enemies. It might be difficult to run past the enemy in the tunnel, but if you roll past him it's possible. The sorcerer is quite a difficult starting class because it has very low strength and dexterity to have some melee power. The sorcerer has a dagger as a starting weapon though, so try to circle around enemies and backstab them. The dagger has high critical damage and will kill the early enemies with one backstab. You can also wield it two-handed and stun-lock them to death.

Comment: It's a pity, I only just started to clear the tunnel. I do have a few daggers and throwing knifes, between those two items I should be able to make it through. Thanks!

Comment: There are other weapons you can use. The dagger you start with isn't actually too shabby, and there are other weapons you can find, like a short sword, that you can use to help fight off enemies until you get through. While it might not be the primary offensive method, there's nothing stopping you from using other equipment in the meantime.

Comment: @Ben I only mentioned the dagger because the sorcerer starts with only 3 strength and 7 dexterity, so the dagger is the only usable weapon without investing levels into those stats first (which is probably a good idea anyways).